# HTML code to complete my Form

Tags: html

I have created a form using html. I need to do calculations using the form and the score should be displayed at the bottom in Test4, And if the score should be pass or fail. If there is zero tolerance then it should make the score as 0% and result as fail. manojhnikam@outlook.com

Comment: This is very unclear. Could you please add some code and explain what calculations you need to do with your form, and what is exactly not working?

Comment: What have you tried? Where's your form code, your HTML, and JavaScript since HTML can't do this alone?

Comment: HTML is a  markup language and has no ability to run calculations. You need to add something that does the processing of the input (be that JavaScript / PHP / ...).

Comment: On top of the comments above also keep in mind that if the results of this test are important the scoring should be calculated server side. Using only JavaScript and HTML will allow the users to fake the results without you knowing.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. HTML does not have this capability.

A form is designed to send the data entered in it over HTTP to a web server.

Software (which could be written in any programming language you like) then reads the data and generates a suitable HTTP response. You need to pick an HTTP server and a programming language and then learn how to use them together to perform **server side programming**.

It is also possible to process data in the browser itself using JavaScript. You wouldn't be able to conveniently write to an existing file there though.